# i want to send id through url after the ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssXDl.png)

this is my table...

jquery:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function(){

                        $(document).on('keydown','#search',function(){

                            var a = $(this).val();


                            $.ajax({

                                type:'get',
                                url: '{{URL::to('dashboard/Grafias-Domain-Search')}}',
                                data:{'id':a},
                                success:function(datas){

                                   /*   $("#dom").html(response);*/


                                 $("#dom").empty();
                                  $.each(datas,function(i,data){


                  $("#dom").append('<tr>'+ '<td>'+data.client_id+'<td>'+data.domain_name+'</td>'+
                      '<td>'+data.domain_status+'</td>'+'<td>'+data.expiry_date+'</td>'+'<td>' +
                      '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{route('domain-details')}}">See more</a>'+'</td>'+
                      '</tr>');

                                  });


                                }
                            });

                        });


                    });

                </script>
```

Controller:

public function domain_details(Request $request){

```
    $datas = Domain_Detail::find($request->id);
    return view('backend.f_pages.domain.domaindetails',compact('datas'));

}
```

after the search result..when user click in seemore button i want to send the id of the user to see the remaining details of the specific user

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{route('domain_details',$id)}}">See more</a>

Route::get('/domain_details/{id}', ['as' => 'domain_details', 'uses' => 'ControllerName@domain_details']);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to change your ajax section.

```
                        $.ajax({

                            type:'get',
                            url: '{{URL::asset('dashboard/Grafias-Domain-Search')}}',
                            data:{ id : a },
                            . . .
```